# need search boxes aligned side by side on my webpage

Tags: html, css

Is there html/css code that can let me put some search boxes side by side instead of one below the other? They are around 12 boxes and I want to put 3 below each other in 4 columns. Can it be done by bootstrap?

ps. I'm not familiar with frontend frameworks and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the documentation first, before asking as this is one of the simplest things though I have written it down for you so that you can understand it.

As you described in your query 3 rows and 4 columns. We know that there are 12 columns in a row so we can divide each division with col-3 that is giving 3 units of width to a box and apply the same row 3 number of times to get your desired result.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">
            <h1>...</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="col-3">
            <h1>...</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="col-3">
            <h1>...</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="col-3">
            <h1>...</h1>
          </div>
      </div>  
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">
            <h1>...</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="col-3">
            <h1>...</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="col-3">
            <h1>...</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="col-3">
            <h1>...</h1>
          </div>
      </div>  
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">
            <h1>...</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="col-3">
            <h1>...</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="col-3">
            <h1>...</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="col-3">
            <h1>...</h1>
          </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also go with using tables in bootstrap. Much cleaner.

```
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Your content</td>
      <td>Your content</td>
      <td>Your content</td>
      <td>Your content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Your content</td>
      <td>Your content</td>
      <td>Your content</td>
      <td>Your content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Your content</td>
      <td>Your content</td>
      <td>Your content</td>
      <td>Your content</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```